# Python logging: capture a portion of log messages?

Tags: python, logging

I am using the standard `RotatingFileHandler` configured via a dictionary in my application. This works perfectly well.

There is a portion of my application that processes thousands of tasks concurrently. I would like to be able to get hold of all the log messages associated with a given task and persist them down with that task to allow for better diagnosis of problems later on.

Each task is processed on its own thread and multiple tasks are processed concurrently.

Seeing this post, [Including previously logged events in a new logging handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895320/including-previously-logged-events-in-a-new-logging-handler) I tried adding a `MemoryHandler` to my logger at the start of the task and then removing it at the end, like so:

```
import logging.handlers
import StringIO

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def do_task():
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    s = StringIO.StringIO()
    streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler(s)
    streamhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    memoryhandler = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(1024*10, logging.DEBUG, streamhandler)
    logger.addHandler(memoryhandler)    

    logger.info("a log message")

    memoryhandler.flush()
    memoryhandler.close()
    logger.removeHandler(memoryhandler)
```

This does seem to work. `s` contains all log messages at the end. My questions are:

1. Will this work with multiple threads each running through the `do_task` function i.e. a log message won't incorrect appear in another task's logs
2. Is this the best way to do this?

I have tested (1) using the multiprocessing module and it does seem to be fine but confirmation would be good.

Comment: You would have multiple handlers open at the same time and they would get each others messages. You'd also need to call removeHandler or they'd stack up fast.

Comment: Thanks - added the removeHandler call